# uiWebView displays a blank white page for a certain site

Tags: ios, swift2

My swift 2.1.1 project displays other sites but not http://html5test.com which my browsers are able to display.

If I need to enable html5. Please show me how? if not, please indicate a fix.

I am trying to find out if my html5 code will run on the uiWebView.
Thanks

```
    @IBOutlet weak var mainWV: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL (string: "http://html5test.com");
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    mainWV.loadRequest(requestObj);
}
```

The error show below after direction from some comments:

> 2016-01-02 12:08:25.949 myWebApp1[3783:886373] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

Comment: Explain what "not" and "display" mean. What happens when you run your code? Have you taken into account that iOS 9 by default doesn't do `http` sites?

Comment: Thanks matt, I edited the title for clearification.

Comment: But you didn't answer my question. This is an `http` site. I would _expect_ it not to load in iOS 9.

Comment: I need to read/study more about this. i have not taken into account something I am not aware off :) Maybe you can shed some more light. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set your web is https. If you dont' want it you have to add to plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
   <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>
```

You do this you will see:
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Or you can set an exception in the plist for specific HTTP domains:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>apple.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
     </dict>
```